# Apache Solr How to Connect?

Tags: 7, search

Running Drupal site and running Solr cannot connect.

I have installed a clean Drupal 7.34. It runs fine.

I have installed a clean `solr-4.10.3`. It runs fine.

I've installed `apachesolr-7.x-1.7` and followed the instructions in the README.txt almost to the letter. Where it says things like

> Move apache-solr-1.4.1/example/solr/conf/schema.xml and rename it to
>   something like schema.bak. Then move the solr-conf/solr-1.4/schema.xml
>   that comes with this Drupal module to take its place.

I've had to change `.../example/solr/conf` to `.../example/solr/collection1/conf`.

Now when I try the test URLs in the README file they work fine, but when I try
"test connection" from Drupal it says "Your site was unable to contact the Apache Solr server."

I've also tried the recipe at

https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-solr-use-drupal

Again, I manage to get solr running, now in tomcat, but the same connection error pops up when I try connecting from Drupal.

Please, what am I missing? Are there logs for apachesolr that might help me see why this connection is failing?

Comment: are you able to view the solr instance in your browser?  Have you checked your iptables?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Darvanen. Yes, I can view and query my solar instance in the browser and my iptables is not stopping any traffic on my local private net.

Comment: Maybe attempt the connection again and then go to `admin/reports/dblog` to see if there is any more information?

Comment: Thanks again for following up Darvanen. I was worried that I'd set something in drupal that prevented it from working and since it's only a dev enviroment I decided to reinstall drupal. That seems to have solved the problem (so far). Sadly, my "solution" doesn't tell me what was actually wrong!

Comment: Yeah it sucks when that happens!  Glad it's working now.